# online server wont show string values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, php-5.3

i have this code, where i get an array and make it a string, on my localhost show the values correctly (1,2...) but on my online server shows (,,) no numbers, just the commas. Does someone know what this issue may be?

Heres my code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
CONECTION

$sql = "select id  from table where id=1";
$result = mysql_query( $sql);
$myArray= array() ; //Here you must declare it as array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$popurl = $row['id '];

$myArray[] = $popurl;
}

$string = "" . implode(", ", $myArray) . "" ; 

echo $string;

?>
```

Please need help

Comment: Why does it say "CONECTION" in the code?

Comment: there is included my connection to the database, sory for thar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple typo problem:

`$row['id ']` is not defined. Correct it to `$row['id']` and you should be fine.